# append value to element with javascript (not jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, append

```
<script>
var cool = "cool";
var pass = document.getElementById('name');
pass.innerHTML = cool;
</script>
<small id="name"></small>
```

To be honest I am just not searching correctly; this seems very basic. I have been using jquery for everything, but never actually used much JS by itself, so I am wondering how one would append a value to an element using just JS.

Comment: What you have done is correct... What is your exact question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code should work, but you need to add it **after** the element is defined, otherwise `document.getElementById('name')` will return null as `name` element doesn't exist yet.

```
<small id="name"></small>
<script>
var cool = "cool";
var pass = document.getElementById('name');
pass.innerHTML = cool;
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work... you have to define the JS after

```
<small id="name"></small>
```

If not there might be a problem which try to search DOM element before it loads

Comment: yes.. what is wrong in the answer?? is that means answer is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Basically you executing the javascript before creating the html

`<small id="name"></small>`

so the javascript does not work on the non-existent html .